# Project loaded but Composer loading makes "Not Responding"

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-2.18, loading

I am using QGIS 2.18.6 and have big project (200+layers) which doesn't have problem with loading, but there is Composer attached to it and it is loaded only to 50% and then it says "Not Responding". I never had this problem before. it actually started yesterday when I imported different Composer style - it crashed and from that moment I can't load my project.

Other Projects and attached Composers are working fine.

Is there any way how to remove composer from project before actually loading it?

I tried to Google where Composer files are saved but couldn't find it, even QGIS folders in my PC doesn't look like there is something saved.

I am using Windows 10 and have high spec PC so it can't be any issue with not enough hardware to load it.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Joseph, you are genius! I was thinking it must be saved somewhere but never actually opened .qgs in notepad. It is fixed now! I removed it, loaded project without any problem and loaded back Composer. No crashes. Thank you!

Comment: Most welcome, glad it helped! Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others (I thought a similar question was asked before but can't find it...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The composer information is stored in your project file (.qgs). You can manually remove them by using a text editor. They're normally headed with:

```
<Composer title="example_name" visible="0">
```

and ends with:

```
</Composer>
```

If you remove these lines and everything in-between, you would remove this particular composer. You can then repeat this for any other composers you no longer need.

---

Example:

```
<Composer title="example_name" visible="0">
  <Composition resizeToContentsMarginLeft="0" snapping="0" showPages="1" guidesVisible="1" resizeToContentsMarginTop="0" worldFileMap="" alignmentSnap="1" printResolution="300" paperWidth="297" gridVisible="0" snapGridOffsetX="0" smartGuides="1" snapGridOffsetY="0" resizeToContentsMarginRight="0" snapTolerancePixels="5" printAsRaster="0" generateWorldFile="0" paperHeight="210" numPages="1" snapGridResolution="10" resizeToContentsMarginBottom="0">
    <symbol alpha="1" clip_to_extent="1" type="fill" name="">
      <layer pass="0" class="SimpleFill" locked="0">
        <prop k="border_width_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
        <prop k="color" v="255,255,255,255"/>
        <prop k="joinstyle" v="miter"/>
        <prop k="offset" v="0,0"/>
        <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
        <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
        <prop k="outline_color" v="0,0,0,255"/>
        <prop k="outline_style" v="no"/>
        <prop k="outline_width" v="0.26"/>
        <prop k="outline_width_unit" v="MM"/>
        <prop k="style" v="solid"/>
      </layer>
    </symbol>
    <customproperties/>
  </Composition>
</Composer>
```